# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'ddlClients'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

please help i am new , i face above problem when i click to Edit my data and save changes it show me the above mention error using asp.net mvc5 . please anyone help me and solve my problem.
Thanks

View

```
>  @Html.DropDownList("ddlClients", ClientItems, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

> Controller

```
  [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult EditCase(int id)
    {
        using (EventContext dbContext = new EventContext())
        {
            IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = dbContext.Users.Where(x => x.RoleID == 3).Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.UserID.ToString(),
                Text = c.FirstName
            });

            ViewBag.ClientList = items.ToList();
            Cases cases = dbContext.Cases.Where(c=> c.CaseID== id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(cases);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditCase(Cases cases)
    {
        using (EventContext dbContext = new EventContext())
        {
            dbContext.Cases.Add(cases);
            dbContext.Entry(cases).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: After save change you are returning null value to dropdown. so either pass model cases or initialize viewbag before returning to view.   return View(cases);

Comment: Sir how to initialize view bag before returning to view, can you do practical using my controller plz sir.